# How to show default choice in JavaFX ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx

I have made 3 ChoiceBoxes with JavaFX8. However, I am unable to set a default choice for any of these
such that it will show what you are picking

Here is my code

```
    ChoiceBox alienchoice = new ChoiceBox();
    alienchoice.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    alienchoice.setValue("default");
    alienchoice.getItems().addAll("10", "12", "14","16","18","20");
    alienchoice.setTranslateX(37);
    alienchoice.setTranslateY(135);
    alienchoice.setPrefWidth(110);
```

I have tried to use .getSelectionModel().selectFirst() and .setValue("default") with no success. I am unable to find out how to do this off my own research.

Visual Example: http://puu.sh/eugPj/57671053b9.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
alienchoice.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

there are no items in the choice box, so nothing is selected (and anyway, you immediately try to select something else via a call to `setValue(...)`).

```
alienchoice.setValue("default");
```

will not work either, because "default" is not one of the values in the choice box.

You can do

```
alienchoice.setValue("16");
```

(for example)

or you can call

```
alienchoice.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

*after* you call alienchoice.getItems().addAll(...);`